# Show the entire output when pandas dataframe is big (when many nan values in multiple columns need to be shown)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, printing

What kind of pandas display setting (or whatever) is required if I want to see the entire output of the following :

[image]

As you can see there are only few lines but I would like to see everything (669 in total) where I would be able to see each line individually to see how many nan values there are in total per line (such that I find the 27 along the dataframe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
DataFrame.to_string()
```

Or:

```
DataFrame.to_markdown()
```

Or:

```
pandas.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
```

Now you could decide to just display NaN values like this:

-by column:

```
df[df['column name'].isna()]
```

-or for entire dataframe:

```
df[df.isna().any(axis=1)]
```